# Fastest way to lookup keywords. Any language, any system

Tags: database, lookup, keyword, performance

Daily I have 5 million or so unique keywords with an impression count for each one.  I want to be able to look these keywords up by certain words so for instance if I have "ipod nano 4GB" I want to be able to pull that out if I search for "ipod", "nano", or "4GB".  mySQL can't seem to handle that much data for what I want, I've tried Berkeley but that seems to crash with too many rows and it's slower. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite happy with [the Xapian search engine library](http://xapian.org/). Although it sounds like it might be overkill for your scenario, maybe you just want to chuck your data into a big hashtable, like perhaps [memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/)?

Answer (score 1):

you can try free text on mssql.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx

Example query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM searchtable 
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(searchtable, [SEARCH_TEXT], 'query string') AS KEY_TBL
ON searchtable.SEARCH_ID = KEY_TBL.[KEY] 
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC
```

Josh

Answer (score 1):

A [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) index might work. Ive used it for pretty big datasets before. It's developed in java but there is also a .NET version.

Comment: I guesst that currently best way is using Lucene. My company is using for large databases and simultaneous request (aprox. 300req/s).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [fulltext search in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) ? Because if you tried it with LIKE comparison, I see why it was slow :).

Answer (score 0):

That workload and search pattern is trivial for PostgreSQL with its integrated full text search functionality (integrated as of 8.4 which is now in RC status.  It's a contrib module prior to that.)